# EF automatic type per table mapping strategy

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a base class called Base, and few inherited classes called Derived1 and Derived2. To place classes in separate tabels we can using attributes or fluentAPI, but in this case we have writing this all the time when defining new classes, but new inherited classes are frequent.

In the end, all work with base's successors must go through Bases of LolContext.

So, is it possible to make EF map all classes that inherits from Base at corresponding tabels automaticaly?

```
public class OneContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Base> Bases { get; set; }

    public OneContext()
        : base("OneDatabase")
    {

    }
}

public class Base
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class Derived1 : Base
{
    public int prop { get; set; }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    public int prop { get; set; }
}
```

**#Update1**

I will clarify my question.

Is there any method to put all 'Base' inherited classes in theirs names named tabels(or some kind of names or id) without specifying [Table("")] atribute for every new successor and defining new DbSet<> for every new successor in OneContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to configure EF to automatically use TPT over TPH.  The only requirement for implementing TPT, however, is to explicitly set a table name for derived entity classes (which can be as simple as using the `TableAttribute` on the class definition).  Creating a `DbSet<T>` property for the derived entity class is optional.

Comment: Answer is the same - you cannot avoid explicitly specifying the names of TPT inherited tables (this is the only configuration difference b/t TPT and TPH).  You do NOT need to create a `DbSet` property for each TPT entity.